# Increase amplitude only on one side of a sine wave

Tags: trigonometry

I have a simple sine function:

y = sin(x) + 1

How can I modify the equation, or even add/ multiply with another equation, such that if I change a parameter, only the amplitude on the top increases/ decreases? The bottom remains at y = 0.

Comment: What do you need this for? Do you need differentiability? If not, you can just take $y=\sin(x)+1+a(\sin(x))_+$, where $(\cdot)_+$ is the positive part.

Comment: y=c(sin(x)+1), for c > 0.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. I need this for some servos I am controlling with a python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y = \alpha \left( \sin(x) + 1 \right)$ for $\alpha > 0$.

Comment: I would like to recognize that this answer was also provided by @herb steinberg. My account is too new to upvote his comment. Thank You all for your time (and knowledge)

Comment: I upvoted his comment on your behalf

Answer (score 1):

Sine/Cosine curves have minimum value $-1$. Add $1$. Embed constants to form product of many such functions. Multiply by any positive constant.

[image]